# Scrapy: Using SQLAlchemy in scrapy has "NameError: name 'connection' is not defined"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, scrapy

Using SQLAlchemy in scrapy has `NameError`, the error message as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\weibo_spider\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "e:\weibo_spider\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 79, in crawl
    yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
NameError: name 'connection' is not defined
```

And here is my `Scrapy` `Pipeline` class:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from .models import MyModel # my sqlalchemy model


class WeiboSpiderPipeline(object):

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        # using pymysql as the conncetor
        engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root@localhost/wbspider_data')
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        self.conn = engine.connect()
        self.session = Session(bind=connection)

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.conn.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item
```

I test the model in command line, it can work, but it occur the `NameError` after I run the `scrapy crawl myspidername` command.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this approach.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# it will send the connection back to the pool of connections in the engine, but it will not close the connection instead it will make the connection idle
session.close()
# to close the engine having pool of connections will close all the idle connections in the pool
engine.dispose()()


# for directing close the connection on session.close, use this code
# Disabling pooling using NullPool:

from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
engine = create_engine(
      'postgresql+psycopg2://scott:tiger@localhost/test',
      poolclass=NullPool)
session.close()
```

Comment: How can I close the connect if do like this?

Comment: Ok, it works. And, Can I just call the `engine.close()`? Or, I have to call `session.close()` and then `engine.close()`?

Comment: yes, it will not close it if you don't call this ```session.close()``` because ```engine.dispose()``` only close the idle connections. you can see this documentation http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html#sqlalchemy.pool.Pool.dispose.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have a very simple error in your code.

If you look at this line:

`self.session = Session(bind=connection)`

You will notice that you haven't defined the connection variable anywhere. So hence the error *(connection not defined)* you are receiving.

You should replace that line with this instead:

`self.session = Session(bind=self.conn)`